# Getting an <input> button and an <a> to equal size in HTML

Tags: html, css, input, hyperlink

I've run across the following issue in HTML/CSS: For my (offline) site, there are a link and a  submit button (which is inside  a form) right next to each other, like this:

```
<a href='settings.php' class='button'>Settings </a>

<form action='processing/logout.php' method='POST' class='inline'>
    <input type='submit' value='Sign out' class='redbutton'>
</form>
```

When both of the elements are links, then they line up next to each other perfectly. Now, however, even though the link and button have the same CSS styling associated with them, then input button is annoyingly larger (in height) than the link (though it's barely visible when glancing over).

[I created a jsFiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/m5m5M/5/)

People on other forums asked for the reset CSS, so I included that as well, even though deleting it doesn't remove the problem.

**How can I get the link and the input button to be the same height?** Is it something obvious I missed? Is there a CSS trick to get them to be the same height?

Comment: Why do they have to be the same? They are two different elements.

Comment: Yes, but it looks much better when they are the same height.

Comment: I'm confused. One is a button and the other an anchor. How do you expect them to be the same size, when the anchor is only text?

Comment: Oh, the same height! That's a different matter altogether.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The size of the (inline) anchor element is treated inconsistently across different browsers.

The solid solution is to place a button inside a link. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5m5M/22/**.

```
<a href='settings.php'><input type='button' class='button' value='Settings' /></a><form action='processing/logout.php' method='POST' class='inline'><input type='submit' value='Sign out' class='redbutton'>
<form>
```

Note that I have omitted whitespace between the buttons. That's because inline elements show a gap between each other when there's any whitespace in the HTML.

Comment: What security reasons exactly?

Comment: @dotweb Nevermind, I was confused with something else. I have just ran some tests in multiple browsers, and the button <> anchors are treated differently. For instance, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m5m5M/41/) works in Firefos. In webkit browsers, however, it doesn't. Stick to the solution in the answer.

Comment: I realise this answer was written some time ago, but placing one interactive element (`<a>`, `<input>`, `<button>` and so on) within an `<a>` element is invalid (reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html).

Answer (score 4):

Using `display: inline-block` on your `button` class should do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/VB9RM/17/

Answer (score 1):

It's 2015 and you still can't style a link to look like a button every single time (at least in Firefox).
The best method is to give both these styles:

```
box-sizing, vertical-align, padding, font-size, line-height
```

but if you set height to auto (or leave the default value) it still will not match. So you need the auto value for height- Rob W method is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Tom's answer helped me.

Had to add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "DejaVu Serif";
```

Additional I had: margin, border, padding, width

Answer (score 0):

On top of Tom's answer, the important style which is hard to find is

```
button.btn::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"].btn::-moz-focus-inner {  
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0;
}
```